# Is there a way to set the rig driver to switch between two models?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, animation-nodes

I'm a beginner.  I have two separate hand models. I  want to switch between these models using a rig driver so I can change between them whenever I want. Does everyone know the answer?

look at my picture

[image]
[image]
Please don't forget to demonstrate pictures, gifs, or upload blends files. to make it easy to understand.

Comment: i would also recommend to ask for self made video tutorials to make it even more easy to understand...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "correct" way would be to rig the hand with bones, save the desired poses in a Pose Library, and recall them as needed, but I show you a way to use your method because it can be useful in many others scenarios.

Create two empties, the sphere named "Switch" and the Cross named "Master".
Select the two models, shift select the switch and the Master (Master has to be last selected), press Ctrl P to make everything child of the Master empty.

Select the Switch and lock all its Transform channels except X Location.

In the Outliner window open the Filter menu and enable the "Disable in Viewport" icon.

[image]

Then Hover over the X location of Switch, right click and choose "Copy as new driver".

In the Outliner Hover over the "Disable in viewport" icon of the first model, right click and choose "Paste Driver".

Opend a  Driver window, select the new driver, change its behaviour from "Average values" to "Scripted Expression".

In the expression field write "location > 0".

Right click again on the Disable in Viewport icon and choose "Copy Driver".
Right click on the Disable in Render icon and choose "Paste Driver".

Repeat Everything on the second model, using the expression "Location < 0".

[image]

Now when the switch is at rest both models are enabled, moving it will cause the switch from one model to the other.

If the arm gets moved or animated set the Master Empty child of the arm.